# Nginx rewrite throws out 404 Not Found

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

After adding `rewrite block`, the Ubuntu 12.04 server hosting Rails 3.2.12 app throws out `404 Not Found` error when entering `mysite.com/nbhy`.

Here `nbhy` is a symlink under `root /var/www/` pointing to `/var/www/nbhyop/current/public` and it is for hosting rails app. The purpose of the rewrite is to rewrite to `/nbhy/authentify/sigin` when user entering `/nbhy or /nbhy/`

Here is server block in nginx.conf:

```
 server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mysite.com;
        root /var/www/;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
        passenger_base_uri /nbhy;

}

location / {
          rewrite "/nbhy" /nbhy/authentify/signin last;
          rewrite "/nbhy/" /nbhy/authentify/signin last;
        }
     }
```

The `error.log` on `nginx` for the error is:

```
2013/06/09 21:36:31 [error] 32505#0: *1 open() "/var/www/nbhy/authentify/signin" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 67.173.143.107, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /nbhy HTTP/1.1", host: "mysite.com"
```

Before adding rewrite location block, the system could bring up login page with url `mysite.com/nbhy/authentify/signin`. But now it throws out error after adding the rewrite block. What's wrong with the rewrite?

Comment: Did a test yesterday. What we did was to write out the complete URL for rewrite to: location / { rewrite "/nbhy/" h-t-t-p://mysite.com/nbhy/authentify/signin ;} (with break, last, permanent, redirect or without). The URL in browser did change to mysite.com/nbhy/authentify/signin. The error becomes "The page isn't redirecting properly
      
      
      
      
      
        
        
          Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `location` block must be within the `server` block:

```
server {
    listen                80;
    server_name           mysite.com;
    root                  /var/www/;
    passenger_enabled     on;
    rails_env             production;
    passenger_base_uri    /nbhy;

    location / {

        # Matches /nbhy /nbhy/ /nbhy////////////...
        location ~ ^/nbhy/*$ {
            return 301 /nbhy/authentify/signin;
        }

        # Other rules (regex) goes here
    }
}
```

The symbolic link is from no concern at this stage of processing.

You are using [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite), were the first pattern is always a regular expression. [Mohammad AbuShady](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2149092) was absolutely right with his answer of using a more specific location. But using a `rewrite` is not necessary, a `return` is better because we want nginx to abort execution and simply—well—return.

Also note how I enclosed the regular expression within the generic block `location / {}` which matches all locations. This is the proper way to write location blocks according to [Igor Sysoev](http://sysoev.ru/en/). See [this forum post](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,174517,174534#msg-174534) for more info.

My configuration above is also catching URLs with more than one slash (hence the `*`) and is meant as a more user friendly matching because a user might simply type too many slashes. No need to punish them, instead answer with a proper redirect.

I hope this helps!

**Related Links**

- [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

Comment: It works. Thanks. Just a side question: how to use regex for return instead?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? How to include something from a regular expression group in return? `location ~ ^(.*)$ { return $1; }` would do the trick. You cannot use regular expressions within return itself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a URI `your-host/nbhy` which you want to rewrite to `your-host/nbhy/authentify/signin`, which should be linked to `/var/www/nbhy/authentify/signin`, which is symlinked to `/var/www/nbhyop/current/public/authentify/signin`?

It looks like nginx is complaining about not finding `/var/www/nbhy/authentify/signin`. Since you have a symlink from `/var/www/nbhy` to `/var/www/nbhyop/current/public`, there has to be a folder `/var/www/nbhyop/current/public/authentify/signin`. Are you sure there is one, and that your `www-data` user (or whatever user you're using) has rights to the directories above it?

Also, nginx has [an option](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#disable_symlinks) for disabling symlinks. Try setting that to `off`. That's the default, I know, but there might be another file that sets it to `on`.

It might also be that nginx doesn't follow the symlink because you added `last` to your rewrites. Try removing that, and see if it works then.

Comment: In browser typing mysite.com/nbhy/authentify/signin brings up the right page for login (without rewrite). In nginx hosting setup, the root subdir has to point to the public dir of the rails application. Since there are multiple rails apps hosting on the same nginx, the root can only point to a common dir and I guess that's why symlink is needed to bridge the gap between common dir and the app's public dirc.

Comment: Under public, there is no authentify dir. Actually authentify is under $HOME/.rvm/gems/.... But rails app should know how to get to authentify when it sees the request.

Comment: @user938363 nginx is trying to load /var/www/nbhyop/current/public/authentify/signin. If it can't find that directory, it's going to complain. Your request doesn't even get to rails. What you could do is make a symlink from /var/www/nbhyop/current/public/authentify to ~/.rvm/gems/authentify.

Comment: Authentify is a gem and rails knows which version to call when it sees the request (a new copy of authentify gets created whenever it is updated and that  makes symlink linking to a previous version obsolete right after update). What the rewrite needs to do is to rewrite to rails app's public dir and rails is going to pick up from there.

Comment: There is some update in the comment for the post for the test we did yesterday. The post itself seems not taking any update.

Comment: @user938363 would it be possible to build a new version automatically in a static category? You would have two versions of the stable version, one in a version control system, and one that's actually used by the server. Pro of this approach would be that you can hardlink to the second version in nginx.

Comment: Not sure how to do static dir. It was random dir started with authentify_xxxxx which is dictated by rails app.

Comment: @user938363 would it be possible to automatically copy the latest version to a static dir with, say, a cronjob?

Answer (score -1):

why not try adding a more specific location block

```
location ~ /nbhy/?$ {
    rewrite ^ /nbhy/authentify/signin last;
}
```

or you could remove the regex but it would match longer urls like `/nbhy/one/two`

```
location /nbhy {
    rewrite ^ /nbhy/authentify/signin last;
}
```

Comment: What's the use of the location uri? It is puzzling.

Comment: ok nvm, i know the problem, i think i did a stupid rewrite loop

Comment: If replacing last with break in rewrite, the error is 404 Not Found